# How to grow xfs formated disk?

Tags: hard-drive, xfs

Here is the disk, it is thin provisioned vmware disk, and has been grown from 300 to 800 GB

```
  *-disk:1
       description: SCSI Disk
       physical id: 0.1.0
       bus info: scsi@2:0.1.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       size: 800GiB (858GB)
       capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuration: sectorsize=512 signature=4268053f
```

here is the

```
df -h
```

output

```
/dev/sdb1                             300G   27G  273G   9% /data
```

and it stays unchanged when I do this

```
[evn-mrs-slave]~> xfs_growfs -d /data
meta-data=/dev/sdb1              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=19660736 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=78642944, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=38399, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size unchanged, skipping
```

Comment: You must grow the *partition* before you can grow the *filesystem*.  The *filesystem* is within the *partition*, and the *partition* is still `300GiB` large, even though the disk is now `800GiB` large.

Comment: I think this qualifies as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: can you show how to do that?

Comment: @Xavierjazz: [I elaborated a little bit.](http://superuser.com/a/1001486/83694)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You must grow the *partition* before you can grow the *filesystem*.  The *filesystem* is within the *partition*, and the partition is still `300GiB` large, even though the disk is now `800GiB` large.**

### Resizing a Partition

Partitions can't be resized, but they can be deleted and then recreated.  When a partition is deleted, the underlying data is still in tact.  It's not too difficult to delete and recreate a partition, but the calculation must be done **exactly** right, or the filesystem inside the partition will be corrupted by misalignment or undersizing.

I don't normally prefer using [GUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)s, but resizing partitions using the command line is prone to human error, factoring in the partition table (usually `msdos` or `gpt`), the beginning of the partition, the end of the partition, and the right size.

> **WARNING:** Before proceeding, take a backup of your XFS filesystem using this procedure (where `/dev/sdg1` is your XFS filesystem and `/path/to/backup.xfs` is where you want to store your XFS dump):
>
> ```
> mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt
> xfsdump -f /path/to/backup.xfs -L MySession -M MyMedia /mnt
> ```
>
> If something goes wrong, you can restore to a new XFS partition:
>
> ```
> mount /dev/sdg1 /mnt # … where /dev/sdg1 is a new XFS partition
> xfsrestore -f /path/to/backup.xfs /mnt
> ```

#### Easy Way

[GParted](http://gparted.org/) does all the calculations for you:

[image: Screenshot of GParted's partition resize feature]

It's very self-explanatory, and it even expands the XFS filesystem to fit.

This is generally a safe procedure.

#### `fdisk` Way

Use `fdisk` to delete and recreate the partition.  Full example:

```
root@node53 [~]# fdisk /dev/sdg

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.25.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sdg: 991.5 MiB, 1039663104 bytes, 2030592 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FAFC7A8C-52CB-4FF2-9746-391D50BF729C

Device     Start     End Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdg1   2048 1050623 1048576  512M Linux filesystem
```

*Note the "`Start`" position (the `2048`<sup>th</sup> sector in this example).  You will need to type this in as the first sector when you recreate the partition.*

```
Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 1
First sector (34-2030558, default 2048): 2048
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-2030558, default 2030558): 2030558
```

*`fdisk` will default to using the largest contiguous free space.  (In this example, it's the `2030558`<sup>th</sup> sector.)*

```
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 990.5 MiB.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

Now you have a larger partition which contains a smaller XFS filesystem.  These commands would expand the XFS filesystem:

```
root@node53 [~]# mount -v /dev/sdg1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sdg1 mounted on /mnt.

root@node53 [~]# xfs_growfs /mnt
meta-data=/dev/sdg1              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=32768 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=131072, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=853, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 131072 to 253563
```

Boom, you've got an expanded XFS partition:

```
root@node53 [~]# df -hT /mnt
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdg1      xfs   988M   26M  962M   3% /mnt
```

#### `xfsdump` Way (only way to shrink XFS)

Did you take a backup when I told you to?  Yes?  Good!  I prefer to use `xfsrestore` to restore `xfsdump`s onto new partitions.  The advantage is that you can actually *shrink* XFS filesystems using this method, but the downside is that all the data need to be rewritten, which is slower.

You can actually use the `fdisk` method above to recreate the partition.  After exiting `fdisk`, do this instead:

```
root@node53 [~]# mkfs.xfs -f /dev/sdg1
meta-data=/dev/sdg1              isize=256    agcount=4, agsize=63391 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=0        finobt=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=253563, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal log           bsize=4096   blocks=853, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
root@node53 [~]# mount -v /dev/sdg1 /mnt
mount: /dev/sdg1 mounted on /mnt.
root@node53 [~]# xfsrestore -f /path/to/backup.xfs /mnt
xfsrestore: using file dump (drive_simple) strategy
xfsrestore: version 3.1.4 (dump format 3.0) - type ^C for status and control
xfsrestore: searching media for dump
xfsrestore: examining media file 0
xfsrestore: dump description: 
xfsrestore: hostname: andie
xfsrestore: mount point: /mnt
xfsrestore: volume: /dev/sdg1
xfsrestore: session time: Mon Nov 16 14:44:20 2015
xfsrestore: level: 0
xfsrestore: session label: "MySession"
xfsrestore: media label: "MyMedia"
xfsrestore: file system id: c5981472-9b75-4fad-9bd8-d1bd04086f8d
xfsrestore: session id: 092b0cf3-120d-43c1-b8ce-23300abf558e
xfsrestore: media id: 3cc0f4db-665f-40fd-ac54-493625f712f5
xfsrestore: using online session inventory
xfsrestore: searching media for directory dump
xfsrestore: reading directories
xfsrestore: 1 directories and 0 entries processed
xfsrestore: directory post-processing
xfsrestore: restore complete: 0 seconds elapsed
xfsrestore: Restore Summary:
xfsrestore:   stream 0 /path/to/backup.xfs OK (success)
xfsrestore: Restore Status: SUCCESS
```